# How to integration Openstack with glusterfs cinder volume

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-swift, glusterfs, openstack-horizon

I'm  currently using ocata  ROD distbution  and l'm trying  to implement  openstack  with glusterfs  as a cinder  volume. But I'm  getting  module  load  error. 
Please advise if ocata is supporting  glusterfs as a cinder  volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to :
https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/admin-guide/blockstorage-glusterfs-backend.html

> ```
> "The GlusterFS volume driver, which was deprecated in the Newton release, has been removed in the Ocata release."
> ```

So Ocata release DOES NOT support glusterfs.